# Receiving "AADSTS500031: Cannot find signing certificate" error by requesting Azure Active Directory oAuth2-Token-Endpoint

Tags: azure, single-page-application, bad-request, error-code, msal.js

I am receiving following error by requesting Azure Active Directory **oAuth-Token-Endpoint**:

> AADSTS500031: Cannot find signing certificate configured

I'm using the oauth-flow **Authorization_Code**.

The error-code comes from the Azure Active Director Token Service, but there is no explaination
what this error-code (500031) means.
There is only this short explaination 'Cannot find signing certificate configured', but it does not really help me.

Also there is no documentation at Microsoft to this error: [Microsoft Errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-aadsts-error-codes)

The http-response-code is a 400 BadRequest, but I checked all the parameters for the token-request.
It looks good in my opinion.

I'm using the @azure/msal-browser library to call the Azure Active Directory -> [@azure/msal-browser](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-browser)
to authenticate a Angular-SPA.

I'm happy for every little tip.

Answer (score 1):

As I already assumed the error was a result of a missconfiguration within the Azure Active Directory.

After adding a missing SAML certificate it works!

**How to solve it:**

1. In the Azure platform go to Azura Active Directory
2. Click on Enterprise Appications
3. Search for the specific enterprise application you try to authenticate
4. Click on the specific enterprise application to see the overview of it
5. Click in the menu under 'manage' the 'single sign-on' (see the attached image)
6. Click on the SAML pane (see the attached image)
7. Add the missing 'SAML Signing Certificate'
8. You're DONE!

[image]